# Probability of being in a circle, given normal

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, circles, approximation

Let's assume a bivariate normal distribution with center $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Let a circle $C$ be given as $C=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:||x-\mu||\leq R\}$. I would like to calculate the probability of being in the circle, i.e.

$$
P=\int_{C} f(x) dx
$$

At least approximately.

The covariance matrix may be general, but an answer with diagonal covariance matrix will be appreciated, too.

Comment: Realize that $\mu$ has no effect on the probability. So you are free to choose a suitable $\mu$, wich is of course $\mu=(0,0)^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Setup hint:

Start with finding a suitable matrix $A^{2\times2}$ such that $AA^T=\Sigma$. Then write $X=AU+\mu$ where $U=(U_1,U_2)^T$ is a random vector such that $U_1,U_2$ are iid and have standard normal distribution.

Then $X$ has the distribution that you mention and:$$\Pr\left(X\in C\right)=\Pr\left(\left(X-\mu\right)^{T}\left(X-\mu\right)\leq R^{2}\right)=\Pr\left(U^{T}A^{T}AU\leq R^{2}\right)$$

This is not a full answer, but it can make things easyer: the $U_i$ are iid and have a "nice" distribution without any annoying parameters.